# Multiple Criteria Update

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Please bear with me with this one because i dont know how to explain this but still i will give my best. TY

I have 2 Tables and they are.

[image]

and I have 3 Criteria and they are

`Reviewed
 Partially Selected
 Fully Selected`

I have a program in VB.Net that Update the table `Items` everytime i select an item, to include that I always tag it and update `Added = yes` where I select an Item

For example I select `Peanut` then i the output would be like this.

[image]

Now if i continue selecting item then the column `added` will also update in table `Items`

Now here is my question, did you see the `Trans No`? they are both columns of it in both tables. My question how can i update the table `PR` based on `added` column?

Here are the criteria

1.If all items with the same TransNo are selected then the status is `Fully Selected` in Table `PR`

2.If not all items are selected but still there are `yes` in the `Added` column then the status in Table `PR` are Partially Selected

3.If there no items selected/No `yes` in `Added` table then the Status in PR are `Reviewed`

4.How about if the item is `1(one)` only? How can i apply the 3 criteria

How can i make it?

TYSM for future help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) on the `items` table to update the `PR` table. If the `Added` field can be set to `yes` after the record is inserted into the `items` table, then I would only use an `after update` and `after delete` triggers , otherwise, I would use an `after insert` as well.

I'll show one of the triggers, you can create the other ones based on this example. I would also consider moving the logic to a stored procedure that can be called by the triggers, given that the logic will be pretty much the same.

The code below counts the number of records in the items table with the same TransNo and counts the records for the same where Added is set to `yes`, and assigns these numbers to 2 variables (`select ... into ... statement).

Then in an `if` statement the status text is decided based on the logic you described.

Finally, the status field in the PR table is updated - assuming that this record already exists. You need to extend the code if this record in the PR table may not exist.

```
delimiter //
create trigger items_added_after_update after update on items
for each row
begin
    declare all_count int;
    declare yes_count int;
    declare status_text varchar(20);

    select count(TransNo), count(if(added='Yes',1,null)) into all_count, yes_count
    from items where TransNo=NEW.TransNo;
    if all_count=yes_count then set status_text='Fully Selected';
    elseif yes_count=0 then set status_text='Reviewed';
    else set status_text='Partially Selected';
    end if;

    update PR set PR.status=status_text where PR.TransNo=NEW.TransNo;
end //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: All i can say sir is i love you <3 kidding a side works like pro TYSM, this is the first time i encounter this code i want to review it TYSM